# Loopback and passport - AccessToken 401 Permission denied

Tags: facebook, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to see how to use loopback-passport. So I clone this repo: loopback-example-passport and got it working with Facebook and local login. However, if I go to the API explorer and try to GET some users, or my own accessToken, I always get 401-permision denied.

What I am doing is this:

Open up the example application
Log in using Facebook Provider
Get the token stored in local-storage and set it in the API explorer
Make a request
So in the API explorer I'm using the same access token I got from the Facebook provider. What I'm I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be possible that your access token has expired - have you checked that?